# O_NONBLOCK unexpected behavior

Tags: c, linux, sockets, unix, networking

I am using socket and setting O_NONBLOCK with fcntl but still by application consuming 100% CPU. Even I am using select with waiting time 1 ms.

For reading purpose I am using recv.

I tried it without O_NONBLOCK and in this case its not consuming 100% CPU but recv taking much time. I tried recv with O_NONBLOCK option but still recv taking much(sometime 200 ms) time to read. 
We are using select then why recv is taking much time?

I can’t use the first option (socket with O_NONBLOCK) because CPU is consumed and in second option there is time delay.

Anyone can suggest the opinions. Its a client application.

Comment: "For reading purpose using recv and once not setting the O_NONBLOCK then its not consuming 100% CPU and if in this case recv with O_NONBLOCK option taking much time to read the value." <-- I don't understand what this means

Answer (score 2):

select() is optimised to enter an efficient wait state (not consuming much CPU) when you use a longer timeout. Try with something like 30 sec. It will return immediately when activity occurs on one of the watched file descriptors, so you can do your work.

Try looking at your process under strace -v -ttt or tcpdump to look for hints at the high latency, or show the relevant code.

Also be aware that select can change the timeval structure, so remember to reset the values between select() calls.

Comment: 30 sec is a bit much.  About 1.5 - 2 sec is good for a user-requested action, to give them a chance to cancel when the network access isn't working (e.g. wrong peer address or network down)

Comment: The time really depends on what other events outside of the select you need to service. Thirty seconds may be fine for a non-interactive daemon that's only shut down once in a blue moon. One millisecond may be necessary if your process has another thread running `rm -rf /` :-)

Comment: Agreed 30s my be excessive, but select() can also be voluntarily interrupted with a signal. Anyways it should be configurable :). I suspect the OP is entering a busy-loop of recv() and/or select() - strace should show that.

Comment: If you have to drop out of your select loop to poll something, your application is poorly designed. Signal handlers can't do any significant work anyway, so it's easy enough to have them write down a sentinel pipe which the select monitors. Likewise for user input - hook up the X socket or stdin to the select. etc. Unless you actually have an event that has to happen at a specific time, there's almost no reason to have ANY timeout for select at all.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's unexpected. If you set non-blocking mode, `recv` won't block waiting for something. In other words, it will return whether or not data is available and that's *very* likely to chew up your CPU.

I'd also consider increasing the `select` timeout a little. There's no real reason to have it that small since that's *also* likely to chew up CPU.

I tend to use values like a second for `select` timeout since that's the latency I need for other things (like timely processing of CTRL-BREAK signals).

This gives the process plenty of non-CPU-intensive time while waiting for data to become available. If it becomes available in *less* than a second, then you'll know about it earlier (`select` will return).

Comment: select() will block even if you have O_NONBLOCK sockets in one of the FD_SETs. O_NONBLOCK is for i/o, not edge-triggered readiness notification.

Comment: @ggiroux: This isn't really relevant, but `select` is level-triggered, not edge-triggered.

Comment: Yeh sorry me confused, forget that, pax also clarified his answer since I commented.